# Use semicolon(;) in Path Parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI 3.0)

Tags: url, swagger, swagger-ui, url-parameters, openapi

I want to write a swagger API doc for some [OSRM APIs](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.15.2/api/#general-options). There is a `coordinates` path parameter which is:

> String of format  {longitude},{latitude};{longitude},{latitude}[;{longitude},{latitude} ...] .

for example: `51.3462,32.5280;51.3452,32.5280;51.3619,32.5236`

how can I make this format in OpenAPI 3.0 not to be percent encoded?

to allow the usage of semicolon(;) for `Query Parameters` we can [use](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) `allowReserved: true` but it's not available in path parameters.

There is another option to use arrays and utilize [serialization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) to use `style: matrix` but it helps for objects to be e.g. `/point;x=20;y=30` not arrays. it makes arrays for example `/users/;id=3,4,5` not `/users/id=3;4;5`.

Is there any solution to serialize arrays by semicolon instead of comma?
or let the type be string and contains semicolon?

Comment: I think your use case cannot be described using OpenAPI. I'd suggest opening an issue in the [OpenAPI Specification repository](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues) to discuss your use case with the maintainers of the spec.

Comment: Thanks I made an [issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1710)  there.